# Why does skolemization just happen under the scope of universal?

Tags: logic, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

I understand you can skolemize an existential under the scope of a universal and get :

$\forall$x $\exists$y.P(x,y) $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall$x. P(x, *f*(x))

what if the universal quantifier is under the scope of negation? Can you get the following?

$\neg\forall$x $\exists$y.P(x,y)$\Leftrightarrow$ $\neg\forall$x. P(x, *f*(x))

As I understand skolemization usually is used in NNF, but why? what is wrong with the above?

my other question is how would you read this? $\neg\forall$x. P(x, *f*(x))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

We skolemize so that we can find explicit witnesses to existential quantifiers. That is, if $\forall x . \exists y . P(x,y)$ we should be able to *choose* such a $y$ for each $x$. But a consistent way of making such a choice is exactly the function $f_P$ so that $\forall x . P(x, f_P x)$.

Let's think about what $\lnot \forall x . \exists y . P(x,y)$ says. It says that it *isn't* the case that every $x$ has such a $y$. Pushing to NNF, we can rewrite this as $\exists x . \forall y . \lnot P(x,y)$. That is, for some distinguished value of $x$, there is *no* choice of $y$ making $P(x,y)$ true.

Now I ask you, if we wanted to skolemize, what should $f_P(x)$ be? There's no choice of $y$ which makes $P(x,y)$ true. You ask in the question about the formula $\lnot \forall x . P(x,fx)$, and you certainly *could* consider a function which satisfies this equation. But it (probably) isn't a useful thing to study. Why?

The equation $\forall x. P(x,f_P x)$ determines the behavior of $f_P$. You can imagine there are very few $y$ for which $P(x,y)$, and so there aren't many choice of $f_P(x)$. In fact, this condition is strict enough to make skolemization a *very* useful procedure.

In contrast, what does the equation $\lnot \forall x. P(x,f_P x)$ tell us? Again, moving to NNF we see $\exists x . \lnot P(x, f_P x)$. But this tells us almost nothing! Indeed, to satisfy this formula, we only need to determine $f_P(x)$ for *one* choice of $x$. Moreover, we have almost free reign! If we again interpret $P(x,y)$ as being something which doesn't happen often, then almost any choice of $y$ will satisfy $\lnot P(x,y)$. So knowing that $f_P$ satisfies this condition gives very little control over $f_P$.

As for your last question, I've already answered it above. But explicitly,
$\lnot \forall x . P(x,fx)$ should be read as

> There is some $x$ which is *not* $P$ related to $fx$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful! A very interesting and illuminating part of your answer is that F is related to P *f*$_{p}$. Where can I find the reference to this?  This could also explain, I think, why the formula is not read as "There is a choice of y for *every* x such that not all x P(x, *f*(x)). It seems to me that we need *f* to be related to P, to make sure that there can't be such a choice for every x, to have the same result as the non-skolemized formula.

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. I'm not sure I understand your followup question, though... Are you asking why we need a different $f$ for each formula $P$?

Comment: My question is what the index on *f* is. I though it limits the choice to be related to P. otherwise, you might be able to find an ad hoc *f* that relates all x to y which make the formula true, but this does not really mean the same as what the non-skolemized formula means. I want to understand the nature of the restriction on the skolemization, which prevents us from applying it in the way I described in my main question. (Sorry if this doesn't make sense. I'm a semanticist, so I have the interpretation of skolemization in the natural language in mind).